# Why Floating point exception handling doesn't work in Embarcadero C++ Builder in 64 bit compilation?

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point, 64-bit, c++builder

I can't make working floating point exception handling in Embarcadero C++ Builder XE8 **in 64 bit compilation**. 32-bit compilation works fine.
(MS Visual C++ works fine in both 32-bit and 64-bit compilation.)

```
#include <stdio.h> //wprintf
#include <math.h> //exp

int _matherr(_exception *a) //Handles math errors; It doesn't work in x64-bit
{
 printf("Error in function %s:\n", a->name);
 switch (a->type)
 {  case DOMAIN: wprintf(L"Argument domain error.\n"); break; 
    case SING: wprintf(L"Argument singularity.\n"); break; 
    case OVERFLOW: wprintf(L"Overflow range error.\n"); break;
    case PLOSS: wprintf(L"Partial loss of significance.\n"); break;
    case TLOSS: wprintf(L"Total loss of significance.\n"); break;
    case UNDERFLOW: wprintf(L"The result is too small to be represented.\n"); break; //i.e. exp(-10000)
 }
 a->retval = 0; //Value to be returned by function
 return 1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{double x = exp(-100000); //should be UNDERFLOW exception
 wprintf(L"x=%g\n", x);
 getchar();  return 0;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
Set8087CW(0x1332);
SetExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions);
SetSSEExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions);
SetFPUExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: A little bit more code would help.

Comment: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{double x = exp(-100000); //should be UNDERFLOW exception
 wprintf(L"x=%g\n", x);
 getchar();  return 0;
}

Comment: Using your code, I can confirm it works with BCC32, but not with the 64 bit (Clang-based) compiler. I don't know why.